# JavaCompiler: Is it possible to feed in variables on run

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac

I will have to be using JavaCompilers in the near future so I am trying to learn about the basics now and choose the best one to learn and I have come across a question that i could not really fine an answer to online

At the moment im looking at the JavaCompiler. If i have a program X being evaluated and it takes input from System.in and prints output to System.out,
can I compile and run it while feeding it some specific input and capturing it's output in a file?

If so, is there any examples online so i can try understand it a bit better?

EDIT:

Simple Test case to pass in while compiling

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TestSet
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  try
  {
     System.out.print(   "[1]--constructor 1, size, isEmpty: ");
     LinkedSet<String> s1 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     if (s1.size() != 0)
        System.out.print("*** size? ***");
     if (!s1.isEmpty())
        System.out.print("*** isEmpty? ***");
     System.out.println();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("*** CRASH !!! ***");
  }
  try
  {
     System.out.print(   "[2]--constructor 2, size, isEmpty: ");
     LinkedSet<String> s1 = new LinkedSet<String>( "alpha");
     if (s1.size() != 1)
        System.out.print("*** size? ***");
     if (s1.isEmpty())
        System.out.print("*** isEmpty? ***");
     System.out.println();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("*** CRASH !!! ***");
  }
  try
  {
     System.out.print(   "[3]--contains: ");
     LinkedSet<String> s1 = new LinkedSet<String>("alpha");
     if (!s1.contains("alpha"))
        System.out.print("*** elt. not found ***");
     if (s1.contains("beta"))
        System.out.print("*** non-elt ``found'' ***");
     System.out.println();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("*** CRASH !!! ***");
  }
  try
  {
     System.out.print(   "[4]--add: ");
     LinkedSet<String> s1 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s1.add("alpha");
     s1.add("beta");
     s1.add("gamma");
     if (s1.size() != 3)
        System.out.print("*** size? ***");
     if (!s1.contains("alpha") ||
        !s1.contains("beta") ||
        !s1.contains("gamma"))
        System.out.print("*** elt. not found ***");
     if (s1.contains("delta"))
        System.out.print("*** non-elt ``found'' ***");
     s1.add("beta");
     if (s1.size() != 3)
        System.out.print("*** size/duplicates? ***");
     System.out.println();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("*** CRASH !!! ***");
  }
  try
  {
     System.out.print(   "[5]--remove: ");
     LinkedSet<String> s1 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s1.add("alpha");
     s1.add("beta");
     s1.add("gamma");
     s1.remove("beta");
     s1.remove("alpha");
     s1.remove("gamma");
     if (s1.size() != 0)
        System.out.print("*** size? ***");
     if (s1.contains("alpha") ||
        s1.contains("beta") ||
        s1.contains("gamma"))
        System.out.print("*** non elt. ``found'' ***");
     System.out.println();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("*** CRASH !!! ***");
  }
  try
  {
     System.out.print(   "[6]--print: ");
     LinkedSet<String> s1 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s1.add("this");
     s1.add("is");
     s1.add("assignment");
     s1.add("four");
     s1.print();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("*** CRASH !!! ***");
  }
  try
  {
     System.out.print(   "[7]--addAll: ");
     LinkedSet<String> s1 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s1.add("alpha");
     s1.add("beta");
     s1.add("gamma");
     LinkedSet<String> s2 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s2.add("beta");
     s2.add("delta");
     s1.addAll(s2);
     if (!s1.contains("alpha") || ! s1.contains("beta") ||
        !s1.contains("gamma") || !s1.contains("delta"))
        System.out.print("*** elt. ``dropped'' ***");
     if (s1.size() != 4)
        System.out.print("*** size ? ***");
     System.out.println();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("*** CRASH !!! ***");
  }

  try
  {
     System.out.print(   "[8]--containsAll: ");
     LinkedSet<String> s1 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s1.add("alpha");
     s1.add("beta");
     s1.add("gamma");
     LinkedSet<String> s2 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s2.add("beta");
     s2.add("delta");
     if (s1.containsAll(s2))
        System.out.print("*** non-containment incorrect ***");
     LinkedSet<String> s3 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s3.add("beta");
     s3.add("alpha");
     if (!s1.containsAll(s3))
        System.out.print("*** containment incorrect ***");
     System.out.println();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("*** CRASH !!! ***");
  }
  try
  {
     System.out.print(   "[9]--removeAll: ");
     LinkedSet<String> s1 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s1.add("alpha");
     s1.add("beta");
     s1.add("gamma");
     s1.add("delta");
     LinkedSet<String> s2 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s2.add("beta");
     s2.add("delta");
     s1.removeAll(s2);
     if (s1.contains("beta") || s1.contains("delta"))
        System.out.print("*** some  elts not removed? ***");
     if (!s1.contains("alpha") || !s1.contains("gamma"))
        System.out.print("*** wrong elts removed? ***");
     System.out.println();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("*** CRASH !!! ***");
  }
  try
  {
     System.out.print(   "[10]--retainAll: ");
     LinkedSet<String> s1 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s1.add("alpha");
     s1.add("beta");
     s1.add("gamma");
     s1.add("delta");
     LinkedSet<String> s2 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s2.add("beta");
     s2.add("delta");
     s1.retainAll(s2);
     if (s1.contains("alpha") || s1.contains("gamma"))
        System.out.print("*** wrong elts retained? ***");
     if (!s1.contains("beta") || !s1.contains("delta"))
        System.out.print("*** wrong elts removed? ***");
     System.out.println();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("*** CRASH !!! ***");
  }
  try
  {
     System.out.print(   "[11]--elements: ");
     LinkedSet<String> s1 = new LinkedSet<String>();
     s1.add("alpha");
     s1.add("beta");
     s1.add("gamma");
     s1.add("delta");
     Iterator<String> list = s1.elements();
     System.out.print("("+list.hasNext()+") ");
     if (list.hasNext())
        System.out.print(list.next()+"; ");
     System.out.print("("+list.hasNext()+")");
     if (list.hasNext())
        System.out.print(list.next()+"; ");
     System.out.print("("+list.hasNext()+")");
     if (list.hasNext())
        System.out.print(list.next()+"; ");
     System.out.print("("+list.hasNext()+")");
     if (list.hasNext())
        System.out.print(list.next()+"; ");
     System.out.print("("+list.hasNext()+")");
     if (list.hasNext())
        System.out.print(list.next()+"; ");   
     System.out.println();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("*** CRASH !!! ***");
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking. Are you asking if you can feed a Java program input from the command line then see its output?

Comment: Ya, I am trying to learn about compiling Java programs and I was wondering when you are compiling, is it possible to feed in variables when you are compiling so you know what the output should be when it is finished compiling... kinda like the way JUnit Tests run to test code, i have inserted a simple test case that i have wrote up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya you can......

**1.** Are you talking about the command line arguments, if yes then its possible..

**Eg:**

```
javac Test.java
enter code herejava Test Hello       // Hello is the Input
```

In Java this **"Hello" input is sent to the main() method in it String[] array**.

`public static void main(String[] args)`

So to access this `Hello` which you have passed as an Argument to the `main()` methods parameter, you need to do this..

```
 String s = args[0];
```

**2.** Now if you want to **write this into a file internally from within the program** do this.

```
 String s = args[0];
 File f = new File(d:\\vivek.txt);
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

 bw.write(s);
```

Comment: +1 for both answers: I was looking into compiling from a java file itself by calling the JavaCompiler with something like ' JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();'... but im guessing if this is all done through the command line you can call the command line and pass these calls to the command line? (Have not looked too much into the command line yet)

Comment: Ya we can pass the output on the console, and you put it into a file usin `>`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a compilers question. I'm pretty sure what you want is just input/output redirection, potentially with a little bit of scripting.

The basics are:

- You can use a text file as a program's input with the `<` character
- You can use a text file as a program's output with the `>` character

For example, if I had a program in Foo.java and I wanted to give it input from in.txt, storing its results in out.txt, I might type:

```
javac Foo.java
java Foo <in.txt >out.txt
```

After Foo runs, out.txt will have what Foo printed to System.out. Take a look at your shell documentation for more info about text input and output.

Comment: Yes, this is a command-line thing. "Shell" is another word for your computer's command line.